Problems with displaying a html file using docker that is hosting two webservers
I'm new to Docker Compose, and I have successfully created a Docker container hosting a web server. The container is running without any issues. However, I'm facing difficulties displaying an HTML file that should be accessible to my webserver1 in the /usr/local/apache2/htdocs directory inside the container.
When I log into the container using the command sudo docker exec -it webserver1 sh, I can see that the index.html file is present in the mentioned directory. Additionally, I have confirmed that the index.html file also exists in the ./website directory with read and write permissions.
This is my docker-compose.yml
`services:
  webserver1:
    image: httpd:alpine
    container_name: webserver1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - "./website/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge


I have tried researching without any luck, so I'm open for suggestions.
I'm expecting to see the index.html file whenever I type in localhost:8081/index.html in my browser, but nothing is displaying.
